# meaning of 危うくなってきた in this sentence

Tags: meaning

I was listening to bilingual news and was wondering what **危うくなってきた** would mean in this context.

> Micheal: Should I care about celebrities’ birthdays?
> Mami: No.
> Michael: Okay.
> Mami: Well, especially if you don’t even know who they are.
> Michael: Yeah. It’s, it’s absolutely out of control.
> Mami: Like, even, celebrities というか、YouTubersとかもっとわかんないし、普通のなんか Hollywood actors and actresses ももうちょっと**危うくなってきた**、若い、若者たちは。

Answer (score 1):

One sense of 危うい broadly means that something is "(dangerously) weak". What is weak depends on the context - it could be structural integrity of a building, or understanding of something (that you are expected to understand).

The highlighted sentence in the question can be clarified like this with a few more words:

> X**について**も、**私の知識は**もうちょっと危うくなってきた

This can be inferred from the fact the two discuss how much they (don't) know about those people.